# Buy a mac / Get it bought for you / Learn Windows?

Tags: new-job, new-hires, hardware

I am a developer at a small/medium size company that comes from a previous very big company.

During the interview as far as I remember I mentioned I would work on Ubuntu or Mac, but I don't feel comfortable in Windows even though I know how to move around it. (I use it at home mostly just for games, and "I think Windows is not really serious for DEVS, even though you can do many times the same thank with UNIX")

After more than 2 weeks struggling with windows and the poor use it does of the command line and my lack of knowledge with the IDE's I switched to a VM that had a Mac in order to be able to do everydays job.

They didn't want to buy me a Mac because they said I will have to get used to Windows and they justify that saying that all of them work in Windows, so I can do the same.

I don't want to work in Windows because as I said, there is no real `terminal`, you have a lack of control on the system that is huge, there are too many fancy graphic tools that make me loose productivity.

I want to know what would you do in my case since I haven't had this issue ever. **Would you have bought a mac / press them to buy it for you / Learn Windows?**
I just felt like they didn't really care about me at all because they can't understand my complains and see that they were quite fair.

**PS:** Now after more than 3 months with the VM, and after all the flashing problems I have with the display (Happens in all VM versions and several other computers) I decided to buy my own Mac and bring it to the office to be able to work somehow.

**PS2:** I was allowed to bring my own mac, but it sorta pissed me off that I had to spend *my money* but well at least I could work properly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use what the rest of the company is using.

Development teams tend to have similar work and development environments so that in cases of demonstrations, preparing documentation, paired programming etc., we can find our way around our colleagues' workspaces. Insisting on something different may risk alienating you if you are new to the company.

Especially if your go-to OS is not Windows, I would advise checking beforehand what operating systems the company uses. And on interviewer's part, as soon as you said you use Mac and Ubuntu, they really should have at least mentioned they use Windows.

If you feel like something can be improved, or there is an alternative OS you feel could help your colleagues (and you) do your work better, you can argue your case. Do remember that you will really have to justify it in terms of functionality, licencing costs, learning curve etc. Have something more than personal preference as a point.

Answer (score 7):

You're being a bit of a platform snob here.

You have a new job, congratulations.

The best course of action would be to simply get on with things and ramp up your productivity using different tools (the same as all your current co-workers do).

In finding routes to using non-conventional development tools, you're implicitly alienating the rest of your team.

Try fitting in more.

Also, Macs aren't likely to be covered by your IT department's security/software policy or covered by the volume license for the development software.

Comment: The problem is that I don't see any benefict of doing things alike when the things that they are doing are wrong and broken :( env and procedement wise, i didn't want to end up like a monkey just doing stuff cause other monkeys do

Comment: Wow, sounds quite arrogant considered these monkeys did not only create a business that supports themselves but also apparently enough to pay your wages too!

Comment: @Daniel that is true... but it's breaking every 2 seconds :( anyhow.. maybe you are right...

Comment: @Thehiddenname things were not wrong and broken before you got there. The company was clearly running fine BEFORE you got there. I really get the feeling you are just being an elitist. Learn windows or resign are really your only options.

Comment: BTW, I have to say I always "HATED" Mac until I tried it, so it's not like i am a mac user since always... Im more a UNIX that likes the Mac display and style

Comment: @The hidden name: I know this can be frustrating, but in order to improve an organisation you first have to understand them. Meet them where they stand today. Get the whole team to follow through. You don´t do that by just popping in and shouting "Everyone stop doing what you where successful with, I am here, I have the wisdom, I´ll tell you what to do.

Comment: @Daniel I agree.  I believe that there's a different question to be asked (but possibly not on this Stack) that will be more productive.

Comment: @Pete yep, I just posted here cause i had no clue where to put it,

Comment: @Erik: Nobody says there is nothing wrong with the company. Only saying that this is not the way to improve them.

Answer (score 3):

Learn Windows or look for another job.

Really, the choice of your tools is made by you management and not by you. You can consult them that you could be more efficient using a different set of tools, but they do not have to take your advice. 
And there are advantages if everybody uses the same tools, for example if somebody where to take over your tasks etc.

Ultimately, your employer pays for your time and if he wants his source code hand-written on a paper sheet ... you just do it that way.

If you absolutely do not like the way work is done at that place, look for one that is a better fit.

Answer (score 2):

You will have multiple issues:

1) everybody else will be doing things on windows. So you are taking on the obligation to make sure that it appears seamless. If they use outlook then you can't miss a calendar invite because your choice of tool doesn't work with it. If they are using windows based tools to manage the development then your tools have to work with them.

2) IT and security have to agree. You will be hooking a machine they don't control to their network. For many places that would be a show stopper. They might insist that it be air gaped, which defeats the requirement for seamless.

3) They will not want to pay for any software or tools that you need to run on your hardware. They have given you a machine, they are spending time patching the OS and tools. They may have a company wide license for their tools, and don't want to spend additional money on your tools.

4) You might have to show that you are running all the anti-virus tools to their level of satisfaction.

I have worked in an office where several developers felt that running their favorite version of Linux was the only way they could work. In the end it wasn't worth the hassle. There was nothing but problems. They couldn't use the tools the rest of the team was using. They had problems working with the tickets. They had browser issues. They had calendar issues. They had email issues. They had file format issues.

It seemed that they spent 25% of their time converting between the two operating systems.

You need to decide what you want to do if they don't like your plan to bring in your own machine.

If I was your management, I know that I would be wondering how this issue didn't get discovered during the hiring process. If I was aware of your level of insisting that real development can't be done with our tools,  and you are still in the probationary period, I would start to look at how how quickly I can get our second choice on board.

Answer (score 1):

In your place I would have learnt Windows, because that's what the job expects of you, and not unreasonably either. If you really can't work on the platform that *the rest of the company uses* then that's probably a sign that this is not the company for you.

We've all worked in jobs where we didn't get to use our preferred platform/tools and while it's fine to *ask* if you can have your preferred setup instead but if the company decides not to grant that request then you can either get on board or you can go elsewhere. Ignoring your employer's directives and denigrating your coworkers for not sharing your preferences is pretty unprofessional to say the least and buying yourself a mac to take to work? I really wouldn't do that without discussing it with them first and getting the OK. In most places I've worked if an employee turned up with their own kit (especially if that kit was running a different platform) unannounced, with no BYOD policy or culture in place and just expected to plug in to the network and crack on they would be told (with very good reason) that they had wasted their time/money. Particularly where they have already been directed to use the platform that the rest of the company is using instead. I've seen director-level employees get away with it because of their seniority and authority but regular employees generally get told to take a hike.

Comment: You are right in many things, at least they told me I could bring it...

Answer (score 0):

Good news for you. Windows 10 provides the  Bash on Ubuntu on Windows service.

It allows you to use a real *UNIX environment in Windows with full support from Microsoft.

You should be able to setup a good working environment with it.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/about

Comment: If they use windows 10.

Comment: I've tried it, and there are still many things missing, not only commands but other things.. maybe in some years, but now, not...

Comment: What do you miss? You can even run Unity/GNOME/KDE

Comment: I'll take a look to it, btw they use W10, I have a machine with W7 cause their supply department doesn't do anything all day, took them more than 2 months to get a phone and half a year to get headphones... They gave me an old computer they had around after realising that their installation of W10 was not in the SSD, still waiting for the W10 SSD computer... 3 months after

Comment: The company doesn't look good. Better find a new job. Btw give Windows 10 a try (with Bash). It's a good learning  experience